# Use remote .json file in my Jekyll project

Tags: jekyll

I am trying to use a github api to generate content in my jekyll project. Currently I can generate the desired content using the .json file locally in the _data directory. However, I want to be able to use the .json file from github every time the site is built to update the content in the project without having to manually re-download the file and place it in the project directory. Is this possible and how can this be done? Also the project is being hosted by github pages so my plugin usage is limited.

Comment: Where do datas come from ? What is the template ? What is the expected result ? Do you have a Jekyll repository with working code ?

Comment: The data came from a github api. The raw json file can be accessed directly from a specific url. Jekyll works well with local json files and I can display the content using standard liquid tags. I simply was wondering if there is a way to access a remote file using the standard liquid tags. In order to make the content on my site dynamic I ended up having to use javascript rather than the liquid tags built in to jekyll.